# Limitations on Azure file sharing?

Tags: azure, virtual-machine

In Azure, I spun up a dev environment, with a virtual machine. Two requirements was being able to transfer files (upload/download with this VM) and have two separate user accounts that could you the VM. So I implemented the file sharing option Azure provides following this Microsoft documentation: [Microsoft Tutorial: Creating Fileshare](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-files-quick-create-use-windows). Following these steps was clear and easy.

My Trouble lies in the second account, I am able to follow the said documentation and have the fileshare load onto the primary account. But when I switch users and go to the alternate account for the same VM to try and map the fileshare all together, the code replies successful but there is no fileshare available.

[image]

### Curious if anyone has any ideas or guidance right now.

Once I spun up the VM and storage acc (using the Azure portal) I went to 'Computer Management' > Local Users & Groups > Users > Created a new users and added them to the same groups as the primary. Switching to this second acc will not allow me to follow the orignal Microsoft documentation.

No Luck:

-I gave it the weekend and still having this issue

-have restarted the VM still with no luck

-tried different log in method to see if that would help

-Changed drive from Z to Y just in case of duplicates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Curious if anyone has any ideas or guidance right now.

When I tried to mount an `Azure File share` in an `Azure VM` for the second user, I also faced the same issue, but it's showing up in the command prompt.

[image]

Alternatively, you can manually add the `Azure File share` to the `Azure VM` for the second user by following these steps

1. Open file explorer by opening it from the Start Menu`(Win+E)`
2. Right click on `This PC` and select `Map Network Drive`
3. Select the `Drive letter` and enter the `UNC` path to your `Azure file share` with below format and       Check the **Connect using different credentials**

```
 <storageAccountName>.file.core.windows.net\<fileShareName>
`\\khanstorage123.file.core.windows.net\sample.file.core.windows.net\file-share-name`
```

[image]

4. Select **More choices** > **Use a different account**. Under **Email address**, use the `Azure Storage account` name, and use a storage account access key as the password. select **OK**.
5. After entering the credentials, I'm able to access the `Azure File share` for the second user as well.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much this was extremely helpful and was able to resolve the problem!